# Solution of a differential equation that are $C^2(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0 \})$, continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and even

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, even-and-odd-functions

I have to find all the solution of the differential equation $$-y''+y=0$$ that belongs in $C^2(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0 \})$, that are even, and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. This gives me $$
y(x)=A_-e^{-x} + B_- e^x \ \ \text{for} \  x<0$$ and $$y(x)=A_+e^{-x} + B_+ e^x \ \ \text{for} \  x>0.$$
Now i use the fact that $y$ must be continuous in $0$, this gives me $$A_- + B_- = A_+ + B_+.$$
Now i am not sure how to use the fact that $y$ must be even, this would gives me
$$A_+e^{-x} + B_+ e^{x}=A_-e^{x} + B_- e^{-x}.$$
I know that i have to find $A_-= B_+$ and $B_-=A_+,$ but i'm not sure how to conclude.

Comment: $(A_+ - B_-)e^{-x} = (A_- - B_+)e^x$ implies $(A_+ - B_-)= (A_- - B_+)e^{2x}$ for all $x>0$. Thus we must have $A_- - B_+=0$: if not, the RHS is not a constant function. Then this implies $A_+ - B_- = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying $A_- +B_-= A_+ + B_+$ by $e^x$ gives $A_-e^{x} +B_-e^{x}= A_+e^{x} + B_+e^{x}$ and subtracting with the second

$$A_-e^{x} +B_-e^{x}-A_+e^{-x}-B_+e^{x}=A_+e^{x} + B_+e^{x}-A_-e^{x}-B_-e^{-x}$$
$$(A_-+B_--B_+)e^{x}-A_+e^{-x}=(A_++B_+-A_-)e^{x}-B_-e^{-x}$$

Since this must hold for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, compare coefficients of $e^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Ok, so since this is true for all $x$, then the coefficients must be equal.
My question now is, why couldn't i say this directly when i wrote $A_+e^{-x} + B_+ e^{x}=A_-e^{x} + B_- e^{-x}$ ?

Comment: Ok nevermind, i think i understood. the even condition gives me the equality for $x\neq 0$, and the continuity at $0$ gives me the equality for $x=0$, so this is true for all $x$ and i can conclude

Comment: Yes you are correct.